# Simple variable set in awk

Tags: awk

Say I have the following data:

```
cat file
0.000   0.0 425.2   2.23
0.000   0.0 477.9   0.91
0.000   0.0 516.5   -0.41
0.000   0.0 566.5   -3.72
```

Within my awk script `regress.awk`, I would like to set a variable `temp` equal to the third field on the first line, so `temp = 425.2`. Is there a simple way in awk to accomplish this? I can't figure out how to combine `NF` and `NR`. From the prompt I can use:

```
awk 'NR==1 {print $3}' file
```

Which will return 425.2, but I have no clue how to store that as a variable within an awk script. It seems like setting variables equal to a column is easy, but haven't ever seen anything about associating a specific row with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{NR==1 { temp=$3 } NR>1 { /* do stuff that refers to temp */ }' /path/to/file
```

Comment: You are the man, I could have swore I tried that solution, but I guess I messed up the syntax somewhere. Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of NR>1, it seems like after setting 'temp' you can proceed? Thanks for your help and time, much appreciated.

Comment: The reasoning behind that is to make is such that `temp` is only referred to _after_ it's been defined.  You could try not using the `NR>1` restriction, but you might get an error or warning about using an undefined variable on the first record.  If I had to hazard a guess as to why your first try didn't work, you might have done what I did the first time I tested this, and tried to use `NR=1` rather than `NR==1` (:

Comment: Pleased to have been of assistance.